# Iguazio job is stuck on 'Pending' status

Tags: mlops, nuclio, mlrun

I have a job I am running in Iguazio. It starts and then the status is "Pending" and the icon is blue. It stays like this indefinitely and there is nothing in the logs that describes what is going on. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A job stuck in this status is usually a Kubernetes issue. The reason there is no logs in the Iguazio dashboard for the job is because the pod never started, which is where the logs come from. You can navigate to the web shell / Jupyter service in Iguazio and use kubectl commands to find out what is going on in Kubernetes. Usually, I see this when there is an issue with the docker image for the pod, it either can’t be found or has bugs.

In a terminal: doing `kubectl get pods` and find your pod. It usually has `ImagePullBackOff`, or `CrashLoopBackOff` or some similar error. Check the docker image which is usually the culprit. You can kill the pod in Kubernetes, which in turn will error the job out. You can also “abort” the job from the menu in the dashboard under that specific job.